# mongodb-memory-server not downloading MongoDB on lerna bootstrap

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lerna

I have a Lerna monorepo and some of our integration tests in one of the packages is using `mongodb-memory-server`.

Issue is that when I run all tests from the root, `mongodb-memory-server` starts downloading MongoDB and tests using it of course time out. Then the whole test process terminates by timeout before the MongoDB is fully downloaded, so next time it will start download it again.

A couple of points:

1. I understand the MongoDB is downloaded by `mongodb-memory-server` at dep install time. That is, in my case, when I run `lerna bootstrap`. And I am not using `mongodb-memory-server-core`, but directly `mongodb-memory-server`. Given that I see the `mongodb-memory-server` cache in the root `node_modules`, that should be working as expected.
2. Given point 1, I suspect that when tests get executed, they search for that cache in the package `node_modules` and not in the root. Why so? According to [this comment](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1079#issuecomment-337660289) I understand it should be searching it in the root `node_modules` instead.

Here my global test setup, simplified

```
const mongod = new MongoMemoryServer()

beforeAll(async done => {
    const uri = await mongod.getUri()

    await mongoose.connect(uri, {
// ... some opts
    })
    done()
})

afterAll(async done => {
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase()
    await mongoose.connection.close()
    await mongod.stop()
    done()
})
```

Here is my lerna config, simplified

```
{
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "command": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "hoist": true,
            "strict": true
        }
    },
    "version": "independent"
}
```

Did I understand things right? Or otherwise, what should be the whole flow here?

Should you need more info, just let me know.

EDIT: better express my doubts and rephrased question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm the flow is the one described. The missing piece here was the usage of  `mongodb-memory-server` env variable in `jest.config.js` file

```
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
    MONGOMS_SYSTEM_BINARY: path.join(
        '..',
        '..',
        'node_modules',
        '.cache',
        'mongodb-memory-server',
        'mongodb-binaries',
        '*', // MongoDB version is expanded
        'mongod.exe',
    ),
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but it would be useful to clarify why you are setting these values. I'm having a hard time following this solution and figuring out how I can use it in a non-jest workflow.

Comment: The `MONGOMS_SYSTEM_BINARY` evn var is a standard `mongo-memory-server` variable that defines where it should read mongodb executable. See here: https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/api/config-options/#system_binary

So I just pointed to my `mongod.exe`, the one in `node_modules`.

The variable name is `SYSTEM_BINARY` but must be prefixed with `MONGOMS_`, see https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/api/config-options/#how-to-use-them-as-environment-variables